# Checking whether the WebRequest is authorised or not in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a webrequest using WEBRequest Object (with METHOD POST)

The problem is i want to check whether the request is authorised as if i try to pass the wrong credentials the response is UNAUTHORISED

So how can i check without using some try catch.

CODE:

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
        WebRequest.Create("http://......");

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test@yahoo.com.au", "pwd");

        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        request.Method = "POST";

        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data);

        request.ContentType = "application/xml";

        request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        // now send it
        requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: may be using response code like this HttpStatusCode c = rep.StatusCode ? If it's 401 or 403 means you are not authorized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a better api to use than standard HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse pairs.

You can get this via nuget

```
install-package HttpClient
```

More information here [WCF Web APIs](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP)

This allows you to do the following

```
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  var url = new Uri("http://somesite.com");
  // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = set some values
  // add other code
  var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
  if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
  {
        //do something
  }
```

Comment: I cant use it as my website is hosted on shared system and i cannot install anything onto it.

Comment: you don't need to install any thing.  install-package is a nuget command you run in visual studio 2010, to fetch the httpclient libraray from nuget site and reference in your project.  Alternatively click the link in the answer to download the dlls.